# Why dependency defind in lib module is not visible in app module?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android application. It contains two modules of `app` and `pax-lib`. `app` module depends on `pax-lib` module.

I have `libs` folder under `pax-lib` that contains some jar files. I have linked them in to gradle file of this module and use it across this module without any issue. This is how I have defined them:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    // Local libs not in Maven Central
    implementation files('libs/commons-io-1.3.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclientandroidlib-4.3.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/Kahuna_442.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mapquest-android-sdk-1.0.5.jar')

    ...
}
```

This is how I defined this dependency in gradle file of `app` module.

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':pax-lib')

    ...
}
```

I am able to use all classes I have defined in `pax-lib` without any issue, however, I am not able to use .jar files that have defined in Gradle file of `pax-lib` module. My expectation is to be able to use them as I was in Gradle version below 3.0.

I must be able to copy/paste these jar files under `app` module but I want to make sure I am not doing something wrong first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `api` rather than `implementation`

Comment: Awesome, Thank you. This article explains `api`, for those who doesn't know about that. https://blog.mindorks.com/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa